# mysql - can i differentiate values of same column?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to make two or more same values in the same column to be different by database engine?
Imagine that I have column like this:

```
id | votes 
----------
1  |  20
2  |  20
3  |  19
4  |  16
5  |  15
```

I have to make all the votes different in that way that i increment first of two equal values, and substract other one.
After one iteration my DB should look like this:

```
----------
1  |  21
2  |  19
3  |  19
4  |  16
5  |  15
```

Because we still have two same values (id 2 and 3) we keep going with second iteration:

```
----------
1  |  21
2  |  20
3  |  18
4  |  16
5  |  15
```

Can i update mysql database somehow to make that for me? Or should i select values, compare them in php and update?

Thank you!

Comment: Eh? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ***WHY***?   http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @eggyal point taken. My last comment wasn't helpful either. Two unhelpful comments deleted.

Comment: i am just taking votes (answers) for question and i need to order them by vote number, but each must be different - that's all.

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly match your expected result, but may lead you toward an acceptable compromise.

MySQL does not yet have window functions such as rank(), dense_rank() or row_number() but you can mimic row_number using @variables such as seen below.

See [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a514b2/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `votes` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `votes`)
VALUES
    (1, 20),
    (2, 20),
    (3, 19),
    (4, 16),
    (5, 15)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      t.id
    , t.votes
    , m.v - @row_num         AS adjusted_votes
    , @row_num := @row_num+1 AS RowNumber
FROM Table1 t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(votes) v from Table1) m
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=0) vars
ORDER BY
      t.votes DESC
    , t.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a514b2/1/0)**:

```
| id | votes | adjusted_votes | RowNumber |
|----|-------|----------------|-----------|
|  1 |    20 |             20 |         1 |
|  2 |    20 |             19 |         2 |
|  3 |    19 |             18 |         3 |
|  4 |    16 |             17 |         4 |
|  5 |    15 |             16 |         5 |
```

Note that the reduction of 20 to 19 for id 2 appears to be completely arbitrary and that id is used purely as a tie-breaker when values are equal.